# Set empty grid to fill space in a WPF grid

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, grid, space

I've got a subclassed grid with a few extra bits and bobs and I've set it to show the gridlines. I made it so that the height and width of a child spans so many rows as well. I had it set to 16x16 which is set at the start and adds the rows and columns programmatically.

I've done this to set the height/width:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            ColumnDefinition col = new ColumnDefinition();
            col.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
            ColumnDefinitions.Add(col);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            RowDefinition row = new RowDefinition();
            row.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
            RowDefinitions.Add(row);
        }
```

I added children at the start which are 4x4 at one below each other, and that works fine, but it's only showing gridlines for the things that have stuff in it. When I add something new with a width of say 8, it shows gridlines for much smaller columns.

Mainly, I want the 16x16 grid to initially show an empty 16x16 grid on the screen with nothing on it except gridlines. Then when I add things at certain points, it'll add them at the right time and stuff. Is there something in particular that I'm doing?

**EDIT:** Added XAML for `MainWindow.Xaml`Cut out the irrelevant bits.

```
<Window x:Class="OHS.MainWindow"
    Height="440" Width="867" SizeToContent="Manual" DataContext="{Binding}" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow">

<StackPanel Height="Auto" Name="stackPanel1" Width="Auto" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <local:DControl ShowGridLines="True" x:Name="control" Background="#FFDEDEDE" height="16" width="16" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <StackPanel Height="Auto"  Name="optionPanel" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <GroupBox Height="Auto" Name="groupBox1" Width="Auto">
            <Canvas Height="Auto" Name="canvas1" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Label Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="33" Content="Type of Chart: " Height="23" Name="label1" Width="119" FontFamily="Calibri" />
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={en:Enumeration {x:Type en:ChartType}}}" DisplayMemberPath="Description" SelectedValue="{Binding currentChartType}" SelectedValuePath="Value" Canvas.Left="144" Canvas.Top="33" Height="23" Name="chartCombo" Width="123" DataContext="{Binding}" />
                <Button Content="Add" Height="23" Name="addButton" Width="104" Canvas.Left="163" Canvas.Top="190" Click="button1_Click" />
                <Label Content="Stored Procedure: " Height="23" Name="label2" Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="65" />
                <ComboBox Canvas.Left="144" Canvas.Top="65" Height="23" Name="storedProcCombo" Width="123" SelectionChanged="storedProcCombo_SelectionChanged" />
                <Label Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="6" Content="Title:" FontFamily="Calibri" Height="23" Name="label3" Width="119" />
                <Label Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="94" Content="Update Frequency (sec): " Height="25" Name="label4" />
                <TextBox Height="23" Name="titleTextBox" Width="123" Canvas.Left="144" Canvas.Top="6" />
                <TextBox Canvas.Left="144" Canvas.Top="96" Height="23" Name="freqTextBox" Width="123" PreviewTextInput="freqTextBox_PreviewTextInput" />
                <Label Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="128" Content="Position" Height="25" Name="label5" />
                <TextBox Canvas.Left="160" Canvas.Top="130" Height="23" Name="xTextBox" Width="34" PreviewTextInput="xTextBox_PreviewTextInput" />
                <Label Canvas.Left="144" Canvas.Top="128" Content="X: " Height="25" Name="label7" Width="23" />
                <Label Canvas.Left="213" Canvas.Top="128" Content="Y:" Height="25" Name="label8" />
                <TextBox Canvas.Left="233" Canvas.Top="131" Height="23" Name="yTextBox" Width="34" PreviewTextInput="yTextBox_PreviewTextInput" />
                <Label Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="159" Content="Height: " Height="25" Name="label6" />
                <TextBox Canvas.Left="63" Canvas.Top="161" Height="23" Name="heightTextBox" Width="62" PreviewTextInput="heightTextBox_PreviewTextInput" />
                <Label Canvas.Left="144" Canvas.Top="159" Content="Width: " Height="25" Name="label9" />
                <TextBox Canvas.Left="205" Canvas.Top="161" Height="23" Name="widthTextBox" Width="62" PreviewTextInput="widthTextBox_PreviewTextInput" />
            </Canvas>
        </GroupBox>

    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

**EDIT2:** Figured I should show the end result just in case people want a similar look.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could use **placeholders** in the cells when they are logically empty. And a good candidate to act as a placeholder is `ContentPresenter`. They will be latter replaced by the final content.

Comment: Is there no way to just fill it? I've tried adding the ContentPresenter, and that doesn't seem to have changed anything. Do I need to add anything besides a `new ContentPresenter` at the designated row/column?

Comment: Hum strange, maybe try with a layout panel like another `Grid`...

Comment: Aye, I think that's what I tried before and that didn't work either. In case it's relevant, I'm adding the xaml for the MainWindow just in case I screwed something up in there. I've changed it now.

Comment: I fear this is due to your layout: a `StackPanel` will give the `Grid` exactly the space it needs, no more no less. So you should instead use a `DockPanel` (with the `Grid` as the last child) or even a `Grid` for the outer panel.

Comment: Ah, goddamnit. I even read about that before. Thank you very much! I don't even need a placeholder in it, it shows them all now. Thanks :).

Comment: I added my controls and they seem to be fine, but they're not resizing accordingly. Would you perhaps know how to make them scale to fit inside however much space they're given? Thanks in advanced! And would you also like to put your answer up so I can mark it accepted, please?

Comment: I just whacked my controls in a viewbox and that seems to have done it!

Comment: Glad it fixed it. And yes the `ViewBox` is great for this purpose, especially when you build custom controls. :) I'll post my comment as an answer.

Comment: Added an end result image. Thanks one again! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fear the issue is due to your layout: a `StackPanel` will give the `Grid` exactly the space it needs, no more no less.

So you should instead use a `DockPanel` (with the `Grid` as the last child) or even a `Grid` for the outer panel.